# problem when uploading file to google drive with its API with Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a file to Google Drive using its Python API since I need to make a script to upload automatic backup copies from my server to Google Drive if user interaction. I have the following code which I have extracted from the Google Drive documentation.

Code of my Script:

```js
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server()
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))

file_metadata = {
  'name' : 'report.csv',
  'mimeType' : 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'
}
media = MediaFileUpload('files/report.csv',
                        mimetype='text/csv',
                        resumable=True)
file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    media_body=media,
                                    fields='id').execute()
print ("File ID: %s" % file.get("id"))
main()
```

The errors that it shows me are these:

```js
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gdriveprueba.py", line 55, in <module>
    resumable=True)
  File "/home/servicioweb/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/servicioweb/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 554, in __init__
    fd = open(self._filename, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'files/report.csv'
```

the files directory create it manually in Google Drive but it keeps telling me that it can not find it, what could be happening that I can not see? I have 2 days in this and I have not been able to upload the files from the script.

Comment: The error tells that 'files/report.csv' can not be found on your local drive.

Comment: you were right. but now it shows me this error: NameError: name 'drive_service' is not defined, I'm almost sure I need to import something but I do not know what it is because in the Google API I can not find anything about it in the file upload part.

Comment: Right. This variable is not defined in your code ..Go back to the example you based your code on and have a careful look .

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the parameters on line `50` and line `53`. The parameter `name` which goes in the `file_metadata` structure is referring to the **name of the file on the google drive**. The first parameter to the `MediaFileUpload` constructor refers to the **path on the local drive**. For your code to work this file needs to exist. Also you are referring to an undefined variable `drive_service` on line `56`. You can either redefine the variable `service`, which is defined in the main function, as a [global variable](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php), or move the code which requests the api upload (starting on line `49`) into the function `main`. Also `main` needs to be called first before your upload code to actually create the service object.

If you just want to upload this to the root of your drive, you can just create the file `files/report.csv`, relative to this file, and you will have the file `report.csv` created on the root of your drive.

To create the file `files/report.csv`, you need to find the `fileId`  of the directory `files` on your google drive, and send that as a parameter to the `create` api call.

To find the `fileId` run this code:

```
dirp = "files" # Name of directory to find.
parent_id = "" # The id we are looking for.
query = ("name='%s'" % (dirp))
resp = service.files().list(
    q=query,
    fields="files(id, name)",
    pageToken=None).execute()
files = resp.get('files', [])
if len(files) > 0:
    parent_id = files[0].get('id')
```

Now use the variable `parent_id` in the api request to create the file.

```
media = MediaFileUpload('report.csv',
                        mimetype='text/csv',
                        resumable=True)
meta_data= { 'name': 'report.csv',
             'mimeType' : 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet',
             'parents': [parent_id] }
f = service.files().create(
    body=meta_data,
    media_body=media,
    fields='id').execute()
if not f is None: print("[*] uploaded %s" % (f.get('id')))
```

[Here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) is more info on the parameters for the `create` function.

The working code would look like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']
service = None

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    global service
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server()
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))

main()

# Retrieve the parent ID of the files/ directory
dirp = "files" # Name of directory to find.
parent_id = "" # The id we are looking for.
query = ("name='%s'" % (dirp))
resp = service.files().list(
    q=query,
    fields="files(id, name)",
    pageToken=None).execute()
files = resp.get('files', [])

# Create a file object for file 'report.csv' on your local drive.
media = MediaFileUpload('report.csv',
                        mimetype='text/csv',
                        resumable=True)

# Upload the file.
if len(files) > 0:
    parent_id = files[0].get('id')
    meta_data= { 'name': 'report.csv',
                 'parents': [parent_id],
                 'mimeType' : 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' }
    f = service.files().create(
        body=meta_data,
        media_body=media,
        fields='id').execute()
    if not f is None: print("[*] uploaded %s" % (f.get('id')))
else: print("The folder files/ does not exist on your drive.")
```